# Training loop for XGBoost in different dataset

Tags: python, xgboost

I have developed some different datasets and I want to write a for loop to do the training for each of which and at the end, I want to have `RMSE` for each dataset. I tried by passing through a `for` loop but it does not work since it gives back the same value for each dataset while I know that it should be different. The code that I have written is below:

```
for i in NEW_middle_index:
    DF = df1.iloc[i-100:i+100,:]
    # Append an empty sublist inside the list
    FINAL_DF.append(DF)
      
    y = DF.iloc[:,3]
    X = DF.drop(columns='Target')
    

    index_train = int(0.7 * len(X))


    X_train = X[:index_train]
    y_train = y[:index_train]

    X_test = X[index_train:]
    y_test = y[index_train:]
    
    scaler_x = MinMaxScaler().fit(X_train)
    X_train = scaler_x.transform(X_train)
    X_test  = scaler_x.transform(X_test)

xgb_r = xg.XGBRegressor(objective ='reg:linear',
                    n_estimators = 20, seed = 123)
for i in range(len(NEW_middle_index)):
#     print(i)
  
    # Fitting the model
    xgb_r.fit(X_train,y_train)

    # Predict the model
    pred = xgb_r.predict(X_test)

    # RMSE Computation
    rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,pred))
    # print(rmse)
    RMSE.append(rmse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you indented it correctly. You are overwriting `X_train` and `X_test` and when you fit your model, its always on the same dataset, hence you get the same results.

One option is to fit the model once you create the train / test dataframes. Else if you want to keep the train / test set, maybe something like below, to store them in a list of dictionaries, without changing too much of your code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import xgboost as xg

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0,1,(600,3)))
df1['Target'] = np.random.uniform(0,1,600)

NEW_middle_index = [100,300,500]
NEWDF = []
for i in NEW_middle_index:
    
    y = df1.iloc[i-100:i+100:,3]
    X = df1.iloc[i-100:i+100,:].drop(columns='Target')
    
    index_train = int(0.7 * len(X))
    scaler_x = MinMaxScaler().fit(X)

    X_train = scaler_x.transform(X[:index_train])
    y_train = y[:index_train]

    X_test = scaler_x.transform(X[index_train:])
    y_test = y[index_train:]
    
    NEWDF.append({'X_train':X_train,'y_train':y_train,'X_test':X_test,'y_test':y_test})
```

Then we fit and calculate RMSE:

```
RMSE = []
xgb_r = xg.XGBRegressor(objective ='reg:linear',n_estimators = 20, seed = 123)

for i in range(len(NEW_middle_index)):

    xgb_r.fit(NEWDF[i]['X_train'],NEWDF[i]['y_train'])
    pred = xgb_r.predict(NEWDF[i]['X_test'])
    rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(NEWDF[i]['y_test'],pred))
    RMSE.append(rmse)
    
RMSE
[0.3524827559800294, 0.3098101362502435, 0.3843173269966071]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did according to your answer but again I got the values. I guess your answer is ok and the problem relates to my current dataset situation.